# Android - Email validation

Tags: android, regex

How to do email validation? 
I have used following code to check validation for email.

```
final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-    Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
```

The above code works fine, but if I enter the string as `"example@gmail.com.com"` also,
the response i'm getting as `true`.

I need to validate this. How can I validate this?. Please help me.

Comment: This is complex. Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Simply use `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher().matches()` check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18909961/2398886

Answer (score 32):

Use this block of code
Pass the email to this function it will return a boolean value of either true or false

```
  private boolean validEmail(String email) {
    Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
}


  if (!validEmail(email)) {
     Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"Enter valid e-mail!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

U dont need to define any reg because android itself giving functionality to check email is valid is not by `TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString().trim())`

second way is :

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {

        String regExpn = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
        CharSequence inputStr = email;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExpn, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if (matcher.matches())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

hope it help u

Answer (score 0):

Use the following class:

```
public class RequiredFieldValidator implements Validator {

    /** The objects. */
    List<EditText> objects;

    /** The Constant EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN. */
    private final static Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" + "\\@"
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" + "(" + "\\."
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" + ")+");

    /**
     * Check email.
     *
     * @param email the email
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    public static boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new required field validator.
     *
     * @param objects the objects
     */
    public RequiredFieldValidator(List<EditText> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.gangaz.mobi.supermarket.helper.Validator#setFailureMessage(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void setFailureMessage(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.gangaz.mobi.supermarket.helper.Validator#setType(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void setType(int type) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.gangaz.mobi.supermarket.helper.Validator#validate()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = false;
        for (EditText obj : objects) {

            if (obj.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity do this:

```
if (email.length() != 0 && 
  RequiredFieldValidator.checkEmail(email.trim()) != true) {

                //show toast for invalid email

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize pattern as below

```
public final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,256}" + "@"
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}" + "(" + "."
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25}" + ")+");
```

copy below function to you activity

```
private boolean checkEmail(String email1) {
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email1).matches();
    }
```

And call this function with email edittext String.
This function write TRUE or FALSE as a result

Comment: Thanks for the information.Its not validating for the input as "example@gmail.com.com"

Comment: here you are using 2 .com then it is wrong so my function write false as a output.......and i think this is write..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  public boolean validateEmail(String strEmail) {
            Matcher matcher;
            String EMAIL_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" + "\\@"
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" + "(" + "\\."
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" + ")+";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
            matcher = pattern.matcher(strEmail);
            return matcher.matches();
```

If it returns true then email is valid else not.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the easiest and best way we should handle it,

```
EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1); 
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1); 

String email = e1.getText().toString().trim();
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

// Below is the code that goes on your button click
if (email.matches(emailPattern))
{
    // Do what you want to, Allow user to next screen
}
else 
{
    // Show error Message
}
```

Comment: You can have a idea from the link,
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

Comment: You should add some context as to why this answer works. Otherwise, its very short and prone to deletion.

Comment: This won't work..An email is valid if we can send a mail to it.Even `space`,`*`,`%` and many other chars are valid in an email id

Comment: i'I don't have adding a context, because, in her code there're just an email_pattern

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
public static boolean validateEmail(String email)
{
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if(matcher.matches()) 
    {
        isValid = true;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: That has been propagated on a few sites, but is bad because IT DOESN'T ALLOW A TLD LONGER THAN 4 CHARACTERS!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   private boolean validEmail(String email) 
   {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
     String emailPatternnew = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
     String domain = email.substring(email.indexOf('@'), email.length());
     String last = domain.substring(domain.indexOf('.'),domain.length());
     if (email.matches(emailPattern) && (last.length() ==3 || last.length() == 4)) // check @domain.nl or @domain.com or @domain.org
    {      
        return true;
    }
    else if(email.matches(emailPatternnew) && last.length() == 6 && email.charAt(email.length()-3)== '.') //check for @domain.co.in or @domain.co.uk
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work..An email is valid if we can send a mail to it.Even `space`,`*`,`%` and many other chars are valid in an email id